# Protect directory from modify C#

Tags: c#, permissions, directory

How to change directory permissions so that user cant rename it and create/delete/modify files in it while programm working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Additionally there is already a question on StackOverflow with an simple answer: [How to lock files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432050/how-to-lock-file)

Comment: i dont watching how to lock files i seek for locking directories

Comment: Oh, seems that i misread your question. I was never needed to lock entire directories, but accordingly to what you are doing maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433964/can-we-lock-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would have to change permissions on the directory. You can do this using the [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) class in the `System.Security.Permissions` namespace.