# Folder / Directory lock so only running application (and child processes) can modify it

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-locking

I'm wondering if there is a way for a process to "lock" a complete folder/directory and not allow any other process (except its child process created using Process.Start) to modify/delete anything in there. I don't mind allow read-only access, but that's not a requirement.

The idea is that MyProcess should be able to acquire a lock on a DIRECTORY (not a file) and not allow any other process to modify the contents of that directory. It is a requirement however that the INHERITED PROCESS (started using Process.Start() from MyProcess) should be able to modify that directory, but no one else.

I'm using C# (Windows environment).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can monkey with Directory.SetAccessControl().  That doesn't have anything to do with a "lock".  And always ends quite poorly when the program bombs.  So, no.  Renaming or moving the directory so that other programs are incapable of guessing what the new name looks like is a simple trick.  Silly enough to see that the approach is way too flawed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433964/can-we-lock-a-directory

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Because I need to ensure that no other application messes with the directory while ProcessX is working on it.

Comment: Consider checking this question and the proposed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234682/c-sharp-locking-folders-from-being-edited/32235681#32235681

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: No.  This is not a scenario supported by the operating system.